# asking for synthetic control method with multiples outcomes and multiple treated units stats command please

Tags: regression, panel-data, synthetic-data, synthetic-controls, synthetic-cohort

I am trying to do synthetic control method with 2 treated provinces, 10 non-treated provinces, and 7 outcomes. Can anyone let me know which stata command I can use?

Comment: Questions about software are off-topic, but there is a nugget of an interesting econometrics problem. I would suggest rewriting the question to focus on getting suggestions for an approach or papers doing this and then try to find an implementation of that method from there. To that end, how are the outcomes related? Another way to is ask this is what would go wrong with applying the usual MT-capable command (like synth_runner) sequentially, outcome by outcome?